CVS to Gitea includes comments, but clone to my PC does not
I'm new to git.
We've been using CVS and have finally decided to migrate.
I used git cvs-import to convert to git and then I used git push to get it into Gitea.
Gitea shows all my files and changes for the last couple of decades including the commit comments.
But when I do a git clone to my PC there are no comments.
git logs gives no comments.
I have tried git fetch --all but that changes nothing.
cat .git/logs/HEAD gives an almost empty file. So there are no comments that came to my PC.
I've tried to look in Gitea if the comments are somehow Gitea specific and not actually part of the git repo, but I don't see anything that would indicate that.
I need all the comments using a script, since we put that on a website as a change log.
Any idea what else I can try?

Terminology: these are not "comments", they are called "commit messages".

Tried git log after git cvs-import? Were there commit messages?

There is no such command git logs. Did you mean git log? Can you share its exact output?

@Mureinik git log yes

@phd yes, the commits from cvs has messages that was imported and is visible in Gitea

Neither git push nor git clone change the messages.

Since you are new to git and branches are quite different in git and cvs, getting a good understanding of how branches work (both local and remote) is important. I strongly suggest using gitk --all as your everyday visualization tool. I suspect your problem is that your local branch is different from the remote endpoint you want (and notice that git fetch only affects remote branches).
